# How tensorflow works?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use tensorflow with python to recognize some roi with size 28x28. At the first time i use this code : https://github.com/niektemme/tensorflow-mnist-predict/blob/master/predict_2.py, and he recognize 4/5 numbers in 10, so i try to modify the code, now i can see the percentage of precision and recognize 8/9 numbers in 10. The problem is i need to recognize all numbers and i see if i change the posiztion of the 20x20 inside the 28x28 it recognize every number, so, how tensorflow works? I read many documents about tensorflow, and i don't understand how it works, why if i move the 20x20 of 1 pixel change totally the number?
this is my number: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVKmN.jpg, it recognize it like 5, but if i move it 1 pixel down and 1 pixel right it find it like 3, why?

Answer (score 0):

tldr; It's not `tensorflow`, it's the `model`

First of all, `tensorflow` does not do prediction or anything. It is just a fast mathematical operations library with added support for `automatic gradients` and some other nice powers, which turns out to be very helpful for Machine Learning.

Now, onto your question, why shifting 1 pixel down, or above changes the prediction? It's the model (or more specifically the data). Your model have learned something (from the data) that is relative to the position of your number in the image. So, shifting it by some degree, makes the model to predict something else.
Now, to understand it more clearly, you can try training a model on MNIST dataset and then take a picture of some (white on black) number in real life. It's almost certain that your model will predict this number wrong, because MNIST dataset is not a true representation of generic numbers. There are many things that can affect it's output such as lighting in the room, your camera configuration, relative size of the number in the image, etc.